# Hide and Show toggle for multiple buttons - Only toggle one content - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was researching for a way to put a toggle on multiple buttons to hide/show content but all buttons keep toggling the same content.

Is there something wrong with my code?

```
<body>
  <button id="d4btn" onclick="myFunction('div1')">Text</button>
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <p></p>

</body>
```

```
<body>
  <button id="d2btn" onclick="myFunction('div2')">Text2</button>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <p></p>

</body>
```

```
<body>
  <button id="r2btn" onclick="myFunction('div3')">Text3</button>
  <div id="div3"></div>
  <p></p>

</body>
```

```
<script>
    function myFunction('div1') {
  var x = document.getElementById("d4-container");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

```
<script>
    function myFunction('div2') {
  var x = document.getElementById("d2-container");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

```
<script>
    function myFunction('div3') {
  var x = document.getElementById("r2-container");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Most of the times doesn't even show any content after clicking, not sure what to do next.

First I was trying with one button and one function and it worked without problems, but to use multiple buttons they keep toggling the same content.

I must say that this is my first time trying to code something, I'm building my own website using elementor so I never had to do anything like this before.

Appreciate any suggestions (if possible, to someone who doesn't code)

Comment: `function myFunction('div1')` is NOT how you declare a function in javascript - I'm surprised your code toggles even ONE - note: multiple `function myFunction` will result in exactly the last one being the ONLY `myFunction` to exist

Comment: why is everything in triplicate? you have 3 HTML pages?

Comment: @MisterJojo They are on individual containers, I found It was easier to move the buttons since when it was only one code they would stack on each other and I couldn't move them to different containers. If they are separated doesn't work?

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for the clarification, is the problem on the myFunction code or having 3 functions? I'm lost on this so I appreacite any insight, thanks.
I'm reading about java funcions to see how can I fix this.

Comment: both, you don't declare a function like `function fn('whatever')` surely you'd get an error. as for having three functions, if you declare `function fn()` three times, only the last will actually be available

Answer (score 0):

Try like so:

```js
function myFunction(argument_of_function) {

  const x = document.getElementById(argument_of_function);

  if (x.style.display === "none") {

    x.style.display = "block";
  } 
  else {

    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
button, div {
  float: left;
  margin: 2vmin;
}
p {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <button id="d1btn" onclick="myFunction('div1')">
    toggle Text1
  </button>

  <div id="div1">Text1</div>

  <p></p>

  <button id="d2btn" onclick="myFunction('div2')">
    toggle Text2
  </button>

  <div id="div2">Text2</div>

  <p></p>

  <button id="d3btn" onclick="myFunction('div3')">
    toggle Text3
   </button>

  <div id="div3">Text3</div>

  <p></p>

</body>
```

I have added some extraneous CSS to neaten things up, but have otherwise tried to change your initial HTML/JS as little as possible to make it work — and show how the changes did so.